# reduce website downtime by adding two ips

Tags: dns, ip

we have a website hosted in our company server which has one static IP mapped to its domain. Now when the ISP was down for some reason, our website was not accessible.Is there any way to assign another static IP(from different ISP) to the domain? Or can something be done in router level?

Comment: I think what you need is Load balancing.

Comment: It's actually Failover, not just Load balancing. But to answer your question you can create on more DNS A record (or two for the www host as well) pointed to the second IP address. But note that this is Round-Robin and if one of the IPs is down traffic will still randomly goes there. With Failover it will check if the IP is down and will only use the second one (depending on the Failover implementation).

Comment: yes failover is exactly what i need. Are your saying about assigning another IP to the same DNS?@Lanexbg

Comment: Yes, but doing only that will not solve your issue, this was just answer to your question. For the `Failover` you may or may not add a second `A record`, it depends on how the Failover you'll find work. Doing a `Round-Robin` by itself is not `Failover`.

Answer (score 0):

Failover doesn't magically happen either, you have to either use an external vendor that does it (easydns/dnsmadeeasy/dyn/zoneedit/dnsimple) or have something that can dynamically update your nameserver if you are running your own, and that includes monitoring the resource and figuring out when it's down.

The latest PowerDNS nameserver has some nice lua hooks which make automating this quite straight-forward.